# Which one I must use Generic kernel extension or I/O Driver extension for controlling drivers on MacOS?

Tags: macos, kernel, driver, kernel-extension

I want to reach bluetooth, wifi, usb, firewire and other communication interfaces on mac. I want to also doing authentication for bluetooth and wifi. Which kernel extension I must use Generic kernel extension or I/O Driver extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The Airport (Wifi) drivers don't have public kernel APIs.
- The public [bluetooth APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/bluetooth/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX.html) mostly live in user space, not the kernel.
- USB and Firewire device families are managed by the I/O Kit and have public APIs in both the kernel and user space.
- By "other communication" I assume you mean networking? Network card device drivers are built around the kernel I/O Kit APIs, sockets and packet filtering etc. live in the BSD portion of the kernel.

So overall, if you need to get at the objects representing *devices*, you will need to use the I/O Kit - either from an I/O Kit kext or from userspace. If you're using the network (Ethernet, IP) APIs, you'll want a Generic kext.